# How to unset a header when a certain query string is present in the url Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to recreate the following if statement in my htaccess file to unset a header if a query string is present in the requested url.

Is there a way to write a conditional statement matching part of the query string in Apache 2.2?

Any help to write this so it works in Apache 2.2 would be greatly appreciated.

```
<if "%{QUERY_STRING}=~/.*ajaxscroll=1.*/">
        RequestHeader unset X-Requested-With
</if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this in Apache 2.2 with the following lines in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ajaxscroll=1(.*) [NC]
RequestHeader unset X-Requested-With
```